# Twig Template Engine - starting array key with numeric value not working

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I execute a query and use that array for my twig template.

In my html:

```
{% for a in test%}

{{a.H}} {{a.2B}}<br> 

{% endfor %}
```

The column title H works fine, but when I try to use 2B I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected token "name" of value "B" ("end of print statement" expected)

Why can't I start with a number? Is there a way to fix this without having to rename my database column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a [manual](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables), this can be done as:

```
{{ attribute(a, '2B') }}
```

Also you can try:

```
{{ a['2B'] }}
```